# iOS swift transitionFromView disables the whole view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I have three views that I flip with some buttons (at startup one of them is visible while the two others are hidden). Each view contains a view container that embeds a view controller and this is where I put all my content for each view. 
When my app starts I can click and edit the text fields in the first view. But if I flip to another view and then flip it back I can't interact with anything inside that view, nothing happens when I press on the text fields, buttons etc.

This is my function for flipping

```
func animationFlip(fromView:UIView, toView:UIView, animationTime:Float)
{
    toView.hidden = false
    UIView.transitionFromView(fromView, toView: toView, duration: NSTimeInterval(animationTime), options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft, completion:  { (fininshed: Bool) -> () in
        println(toView)
    })   
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your code for adding the viewcontrollers to their viewcontainer look like?

Comment: @chedabob I used the storyboard to add them. First I dragged in a view (this is the object that is flipped) then inside this view I dragged in a Container view which automatically created the view controllers for me